# Website loading super slowly on NET Framework 4.6.2 Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a big website built on Web Forms with target framework .NET Framework 4.6.2 but I have huge loading issues.

Each time I refresh a page it takes almost 30 seconds to refresh it, and this make me lose lot of time during debugging, when I need to refresh frequently.

My website has about 20/30 pages and each page loads from a minimum of 1 to a maximum of 7/8 web user controls.

What could be the reason of that slowness? How can I improve it?

Comment: Not the downvoter but there's 0 chance anyone helps here if you don't provide any details that are reproducible.

Comment: You need to profile your app: find out which parts of your app are slow. Then you can decide what to do about them. Searching for ASP.NET profiling tools may be helpful, though one could also just log some timestamps to a file when certain things happen.

Comment: @mason this is a compile issue (from what I understand).

Comment: @Aristos you may be correct, but we don't know for sure. Once the website is compiled, it should be fast no matter what the compilation settings, right? If something else is going on, such as executing a slow query in a base page class or master page, your solution wouldn't fix it.

Comment: @Aristos that's just one of possible issues and I wonder what makes you confident it's the correct one as there's no default setting that would force recompilation on every request. My guess would be the default sql connection timeout (30 sec) - an invalid connection string would make all requests to fail on sql server connection. But that also would be a mere guess.

Comment: @WiktorZychla we see... I home that this is because of the compiler, this is the usual issue for this kind of delay - if he have an sql connection timeout then I suppose that he see that, the program not work at all and works

Comment: @WiktorZychla ok, I delete my answer, he say that is not that... I was wrong

Comment: I don't think It's caused by a sql timeout. I've said 30 sec but it was an overestimation. Now I have refreshed a page and it took 22 sec

Comment: @Aristos if you're confident that based on the question your answer could have been the solution, by all means undelete it. I just wouldn't phrase it as a certainty that it will solve the problem, and I'd add some things about how to check whether it's misconfigured in the first place.

Comment: It may not necessarily be a SQL timeout. It could just be a slow query you execute on every request. Or maybe you load a large amount of data from a file on every request. Or you have horrifically intrusive security tooling (like my company). [Profiling](https://stackify.com/three-types-of-net-profilers/) is the way to determine where the slowdown lays.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **profile** your application to find out why it is slow.

For an ASP.NET WebForms application, you can use the built-in profiler of Visual Studio as follows:

- Switch to Release configuration
- In the menu, select Debug/Performance Profiler
- Select "Instrumentation", Start
- Select project, OK
- Perform the operation that takes longer than expected
- Close the web application

Visual Studio will now show a profiling report and tell you how much time is spent in each method. Have a look at the methods shown in the **Hot Path** section - those are the ones that slow down your application the most.

Once you identified the method that slows down your application, you can investigate further using the "usual" techniques (for example, set a breakpoint in Debug build and step through the code to find out what is going on).

Comment: I get this error when launching the profiler using your guide: "GetProjectOfProjref must be called on the UI thread"

Comment: @AlessioInnocenzi: I get the same error when running it with Visual Studio 2022, but it works in Visual Studio 2019. I suppose we found a bug in the current release of VS 2022.